# Nice way to merge/copy attributes between two ActiveRecord classes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This has been asked partially before and I found the following [clip](http://snipplr.com/view/29561/) on how to set a class object's attributes all at once, but it's not possible with Rails because of mass-assignment protection. (e.g. you can't Object.attributes={})

Is there a nice way to merge the attributes from one class into another?

```
object1.attributes = object2.attributes.inject({}){ |h,(k,v)|
  h[k]=v if ObjectModel.column_names.include?(k); h
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you can certainly say `object1.attributes = object2.attributes`, but only the accessible attributes on object1 will be set from the attributes on object2, are you simply trying to bypass attr_accessible (mass-assignment protection)?

Comment: I actually have the 3 attributes I want to copy as attr_accessible but they don't appear to actually copy. I'm using RubyMine to debug the objects and even after a supposed successful copy they are still not set to the 2nd object sttribute values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Utilize [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes) with the `:without_protection` option.

```
attributes = object2.attributes.select do |attr, value|
  ObjectModel.column_names.include?(attr.to_s)
end
object1.assign_attributes(attributes, :without_protection => true)
```

Comment: and a little cleaner way to get the attributes from object2: `attributes = object2.attributes.select{|attr, value| ObjectModel.column_names.include?(attr.to_s)}`

Comment: Thanks @PatrickKlingemann, I've updated to include your change.

Comment: I like the do/end in this case also, well played.

Comment: Bingo! assign_attributes without_protection did the trick. I like that you suggested selecting into an attributes hash first instead of directly trying to assign them to the 2nd object.

Comment: Even better:
attributes = object2.attributes.slice(*ObjectModel.column_names)
object1.assign_attributes(attributes, without_protection: true)

Comment: note that `without_protection` is rails 3 only - removed in later versions.